# Object.assign behavior in this case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why in such case,

```js
var a={b:1};
Object.assign(a,{b:a.b+2},{b:a.b+4});

console.log(a);
```

The result of `assign` is object

```
{b: 5}
```

Rather than

```
{b: 7}
```

---

For the record using this I was trying to explain why value is 1 in below code

```
// assuming this.state = { value: 0 };
this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1});
this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1});
this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1});
```

Comment: it takes the last value for assignment, not the intermediate results.

Comment: Why do you expect {b: 7}?

Comment: The expected value is {b: 5}. The first parameter is the target, the second parameter is assigned (first source) but is overwritten by the third (last source).

Answer (score 4):

Because arguments are evaluated before being passed to the function. You're basically doing

```
var a = {b: 1},
    tmp1 = {b: a.b+2}, // {b: 1+2}
    tmp2 = {b: a.b+4}; // {b: 1+4}
Object.assign(a, tmp1, tmp2);
```

You would need to do

```
var a = {b: 1};
Object.assign(a, {b: a.b+2}); // simpler: a.b += 2
Object.assign(a, {b: a.b+4}); // simpler: a.b += 4
```

to get `7`.

Comment: I thought in my case it merged third object (`{b:a.b+4}`) with second (`{b: a.b+2}`) and result with `a`, would not that also be an explanation?

Comment: `var a = {b: 1},  tmp1 = a.b+2,  tmp2 = a.b+4; a.b = tmp1; a.b = tmp2` assign is kinda doing this, if that makes more sense.

Comment: @john no, `Object.assign` puts the object properties from the second argument into the first object and then the object properties from the third argument into the first object. There is no "merge" step (and in the absence of getters/setters, it doesn't make a difference anyway, the rightmost value always overwrites the ones on the left).

Answer (score 0):

It's expected a result.
Because of Object.assign **not sum values, but overwrite**. It set values from right to left. The right value is `{b: a.b+4} => {b: 5}`. This value overlapse other ones.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign` and React's `setState` work differently. For `Object.assign`, you can think of it as a right-to-left merge of the objects:

```
Object.assign(a,{b:a.b+2},{b:a.b+4});
Object.assign(a,{b:3},{b:5});
Object.assign(a,{b:5});
```

However, `setState` is a different story. It is an asynchronous operation. In your case, you're simply executing the exact same statement three times:

```
this.setState({ value: 0 + 1});
this.setState({ value: 0 + 1});
this.setState({ value: 0 + 1});
```

Multiple `setState` calls can update state in one event loop and result in a single re-render. Part of the architectural efficiency behind the way `setState` works may be responsible for this behaviour. This reference may also be helpful:

[Why is setState giving me the wrong value?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value)

If you want to use the previous value of a `setState` operation, you can do somthing like this:

```
setState((prevState) => ({ value: prevState.value + 1 }));
```

or

```
setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 }, () => {
    // In here, the state has been updated
});
```

However, it's hard to give a precise practical solution as your example is contrived and there would probably be no practical need to do sequential `setState` operations like that.

See the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more details on `setState`.